# Can I use Euler approximation for backwards computation?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I want to solve the following Ricatti Equation:

[image]

in Matlab. I'm given the final value of P and as far as I understand I have to go backwards solving this. My question is, can I use the Euler approximation in order to solve this? And how would be that expression, the final value minus the differential time times the right part of the equation?

Comment: When you say "go backwards", do you mean going forward in time using a backward in time (i.e. implicit) method, or do you mean literally going backward in time?

Comment: Well I was thinking going literally backward. I mean, I have a final time, let's say 10 seconds and the matrix P at that time. I was thinking to use a for loop like `for t =10 : -0.1 : 0` and apply the Euler approximation, My problem is that I've been trying to use ode45 to solve this ODE, but it gives me an error (maybe because they are matrices) and then I thought I could use Euler approximation to solve it

Comment: You'll need to run the equation in vector form to make ode45 cooperate. You can do that using the Matlab function reshape (given a vector, reshape it into a matrix, set up the right side of your DE, then reshape it back to a vector). ode45 will have no issues with it being backward in time. I don't recommend trying Euler, it is quite prone to catastrophic failure or extremely short step sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check the reshape function.